# How to convert image file to byte array using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to pass image as byte array to .NET SOAP web service.
Can anyone give me example how to convert uploaded image file to byte array using ruby?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are getting image in some format such as jpeg or png but you need array of pixels for sending to SOAP service. In this case you can use RMagick gem.

Comment: I figured that out, and you right my question is not quite clear.
thx