# Converting image to byte array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a png image as a paperclip attachment and I need to send it to a web service interface as a byte array. How to convert the image file to a byte array?

There is an existing question 
[How to convert image file to byte array using ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405368/how-to-convert-image-file-to-byte-array-using-ruby) but it is rather old and the only answer suggests using RMagick gem (no example code or anything).

Is the RMagick gem really needed for accomplishing this? I wouldn't like to add a new gem without a good reason.

Comment: A "byte array" is not enough detail to specify the format for your request. The service should either specify how pixel data is encoded, or suggest that it will accept JPEG/PNG etc formats (in which case you just encode the file directly as a string). Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Thanks. The interface also asks for the format (application/pdf, image/jpg, image/jpeg or image/png). The interface is https://developer.concur.com/api-documentation/web-services/imaging/image-resource/image-resource-post#postimagetoreport

Comment: The web service needs you to make the body of the request the binary file contents (as read direct from disk) and set the Content-Type: header so it knows the type. As far as I can tell, the phrase "byte array" is just a way of saying "raw bytes" or "the file".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read as binary file and unpack it

```
f = File.binread 'image.png'    

f.unpack('B*')
# Outputs like ["0010010101110010000100110000010000010"] 

# Byte Array
# "abc".unpack('C*')
#=> [97, 98, 99]

f.unpack('C*')
```

Check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_strings.htm) for the different `unpack` options

Comment: "byte array" is not same as String representation of bits.

Comment: @NeilSlater An example would be appreciated, anyway updated the answer

Comment: I have to agree you now show a byte array by any reasonable interpretation! I have also commented on the question that it is not fully specified. It is not clear whether OP wants file contents transmitted or pixels, nor how they should be coded in either case.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted because it is the correct answer. Even though it wasn't what I needed :)

Answer (score -1):

I think RMagic is the perfect solution for your requirement. Check the following link:

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html